# Get all references to a given PowerShell module

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to find a list of script files that reference a given module (.psm1)? In other words, get all files that, in the script code, use at least 1 of the cmdlets defined in the module.

Obviously because of PowerShell 3.0 and above, most of my script files don't have an explicit `Import-Module MODULE_NAME` in the code somewhere, so I can't use that text to search on.

I know I can use `Get-ChildItem -Path '...' -Recurse | Select-String 'TextToSearchFor'` to search for a particular string inside of files, but that's not the same as searching for any reference to any cmdlet of a module. I could do a search for every single cmdlet in my module, but I was wondering if there is a better way.

**Clarification:** I'm only looking inside of a controlled environment where I have all the scripts in one file location.

Comment: PowerShell isn't a static language. There's literally no way to know, from just looking at a script, where a `Verb-Noun` cmdlet is going to come from in any given environment (unless of course you control the environment, or the script contains an explicit `#requires`). Given that, string matching is really not that bad of an approach. Anything more complicated is not likely to give back results that are much more accurate (and the problem is unsolvable in general, if scripts want to be obtuse).

Comment: There isn't going to be a 100% foolproof way to accomplish this. You can use the AST to parse files, but you have to remember that a script can import a module later that wasn't imported before, it can generate or download a new script at runtime and then import it, it can execute code with `Invoke-Expression`, etc. The most comprehensive way you could do it would be to execute each script and then compre the loaded modules before and after, but even that's error prone; what if a function references a cmdlet but you never call the function. Maybe you could do something with Pester and mocking?

Comment: I guess one clarification I should have put is that I'm only looking inside of a controlled environment where I have all the scripts in one file location. String searching may still be the best method, but I don't know how to do that in an efficient way exactly. I wanted to do this for 100+ modules in my environment to see which ones may not be used anymore, so I don't want to go through each one and manually type out each cmdlet.

Comment: As far as the cmdlets being referenced but not called, I don't care if it's actually being called, just referenced. I can make the judgment call of whether it's being used at that point.

Comment: To a first approximation, `dir *.ps1 | where { Select-String -Simple -Pattern ((Get-Command -Module <module>).Name) -Path $_ }`. If the number of cmdlets or files is very large this could be optimized further by caching cmdlet names in hash tables  or `HashSet` and `Select-String -Pattern "\w+-\w+"` to get everything that looks like a cmdlet reference, then probing for membership.

Comment: Oh, and since you want all modules (skipped over that bit) you likely do want a hash table: `$cmdlets = @{}; Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet,Function | Foreach { $cmdlets[$_.Name] = $_.Module.Name }; dir *.ps1 | Select-String "\w+-\w+" | Foreach { $cmdlets[$_.Matches[0].Value] } | Sort-Object -Unique` gives an (approximate) list of all modules used (some modules don't clearly advertise their cmdlets). It's fairly fast on my machine. Producing a list of all modules *not* used is scarcely more involved, but by that time I'd probably post an actual answer. :-P

Comment: Also `$PSModuleAutoloadingPreference` described at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables. In PS3+ one doesn't have to import a module manually to use a command within.

Comment: Thank you, @JeroenMostert, that was helpful. I think that puts me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the scenario, the callstack could be interesting to play around with. In that case you need to modify the functions which you want to find out about to gather information about the callstack at runtime and log it somewhere. Over time you might have enough logs to make some good assumptions.

```
function yourfunction {
    $stack = Get-PSCallStack
    if ($stack.Count -gt 1) {
        $stack[1] # log this to a file or whatever you need
    }
}
```

This might not work at all in your scenario, but I thought I throw it in there as an option.